# count groups of values with aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this one:

| DateTime | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:45 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:50 | 40 |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:55 | 50 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:00 | 60 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:05 | 5 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:10 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:15 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:20 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:25 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:30 | 40 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:35 | 50 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:40 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:45 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:50 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:45 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:50 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:55 | 50 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:00 | 60 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:05 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:10 | 4 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:15 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:20 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:25 | 49 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:30 | 40 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:35 | 50 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:40 | 4 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:45 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:50 | 0 |

as you can see I have some timestamps with values. It is a measurement of a device. It takes a sample every 5 seconds. It is only a subset of all data. There are some group with low value and high value. I define high value if it is greater then 10. If consecutive rows have high value then I consider it as a group. What I would like to achieve:

1. count number of groups in day
2. for each group calculate duration

I will show example of my desired result below:

| DateTime | Value | GroupId | Duration (in seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:45 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:50 | 40 | 1 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 11:03:55 | 50 | 1 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:00 | 60 | 1 | 15 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:05 | 5 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:10 | 4 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:15 | 3 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:20 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:25 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:30 | 40 | 2 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:35 | 50 | 2 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:40 | 4 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:45 | 3 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-01 11:04:50 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:45 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:50 | 5 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:03:55 | 50 | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:00 | 60 | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:05 | 5 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:10 | 4 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:15 | 3 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:20 | 0 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:25 | 49 | 2 | 15 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:30 | 40 | 2 | 15 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:35 | 50 | 2 | 15 |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:40 | 4 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:45 | 3 | NaN | Nan |
| 2022-01-02 11:04:50 | 0 | NaN | Nan |

I know how to read data in Pandas and do basic manipulation, can you give me any hints on how to find those groups and how to measure their duration and assign a number to them? THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `GroupId` greate groups by consecutive values greater like `10` and aggregate cumulative sum by [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), then per `date`s and `GroupId` get maximal and minimal datetime and subtract, last add 5 seconds because sample every 5 seconds:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
s =  df['Value'].gt(10)
date = df['DateTime'].dt.date

df['GroupId'] = s.ne(s.shift())[s].groupby(date).cumsum()

g = df.groupby([date,'GroupId'])['DateTime']

df['Duration (in seconds)'] = (g.transform('max').sub(g.transform('min'))
                                .dt.total_seconds().add(5))
```

---

```
print (df)
              DateTime  Value  GroupId  Duration (in seconds)
0  2022-01-01 11:03:45      0      NaN                    NaN
1  2022-01-01 11:03:50     40      1.0                   15.0
2  2022-01-01 11:03:55     50      1.0                   15.0
3  2022-01-01 11:04:00     60      1.0                   15.0
4  2022-01-01 11:04:05      5      NaN                    NaN
5  2022-01-01 11:04:10      4      NaN                    NaN
6  2022-01-01 11:04:15      3      NaN                    NaN
7  2022-01-01 11:04:20      0      NaN                    NaN
8  2022-01-01 11:04:25      0      NaN                    NaN
9  2022-01-01 11:04:30     40      2.0                   10.0
10 2022-01-01 11:04:35     50      2.0                   10.0
11 2022-01-01 11:04:40      4      NaN                    NaN
12 2022-01-01 11:04:45      3      NaN                    NaN
13 2022-01-01 11:04:50      0      NaN                    NaN
14 2022-01-02 11:03:45      0      NaN                    NaN
15 2022-01-02 11:03:50      5      NaN                    NaN
16 2022-01-02 11:03:55     50      1.0                   10.0
17 2022-01-02 11:04:00     60      1.0                   10.0
18 2022-01-02 11:04:05      5      NaN                    NaN
19 2022-01-02 11:04:10      4      NaN                    NaN
20 2022-01-02 11:04:15      3      NaN                    NaN
21 2022-01-02 11:04:20      0      NaN                    NaN
22 2022-01-02 11:04:25     49      2.0                   15.0
23 2022-01-02 11:04:30     40      2.0                   15.0
24 2022-01-02 11:04:35     50      2.0                   15.0
25 2022-01-02 11:04:40      4      NaN                    NaN
26 2022-01-02 11:04:45      3      NaN                    NaN
27 2022-01-02 11:04:50      0      NaN                    NaN
```

Another idea for count Duration by previous matched value per groups:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
s =  df['Value'].gt(10)
date = df['DateTime'].dt.date

df['GroupId'] = s.ne(s.shift())[s].groupby(date).cumsum()

prev = df.groupby(date)['GroupId'].bfill(limit=1)
g = df.groupby([date,prev])['DateTime']

df['Duration (in seconds)'] = (g.transform('max').sub(g.transform('min'))
                                .dt.total_seconds()
                                .where(s))
```

---

```
print (df)
              DateTime  Value  GroupId  Duration (in seconds)
0  2022-01-01 11:03:45      0      NaN                    NaN
1  2022-01-01 11:03:50     40      1.0                   15.0
2  2022-01-01 11:03:55     50      1.0                   15.0
3  2022-01-01 11:04:00     60      1.0                   15.0
4  2022-01-01 11:04:05      5      NaN                    NaN
5  2022-01-01 11:04:10      4      NaN                    NaN
6  2022-01-01 11:04:15      3      NaN                    NaN
7  2022-01-01 11:04:20      0      NaN                    NaN
8  2022-01-01 11:04:25      0      NaN                    NaN
9  2022-01-01 11:04:30     40      2.0                   10.0
10 2022-01-01 11:04:35     50      2.0                   10.0
11 2022-01-01 11:04:40      4      NaN                    NaN
12 2022-01-01 11:04:45      3      NaN                    NaN
13 2022-01-01 11:04:50      0      NaN                    NaN
14 2022-01-02 11:03:45      0      NaN                    NaN
15 2022-01-02 11:03:50      5      NaN                    NaN
16 2022-01-02 11:03:55     50      1.0                   10.0
17 2022-01-02 11:04:00     60      1.0                   10.0
18 2022-01-02 11:04:05      5      NaN                    NaN
19 2022-01-02 11:04:10      4      NaN                    NaN
20 2022-01-02 11:04:15      3      NaN                    NaN
21 2022-01-02 11:04:20      0      NaN                    NaN
22 2022-01-02 11:04:25     49      2.0                   15.0
23 2022-01-02 11:04:30     40      2.0                   15.0
24 2022-01-02 11:04:35     50      2.0                   15.0
25 2022-01-02 11:04:40      4      NaN                    NaN
26 2022-01-02 11:04:45      3      NaN                    NaN
27 2022-01-02 11:04:50      0      NaN                    NaN
```

Comment: thanks, could you please explain what does this do: s.ne(s.shift())[s] especially that [s] at the end?

Comment: @witkacy1986 - `s.ne(s.shift())` create Trues for first consecutive groups, then filter only greater values by `[s]` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)